# Get rows with condition on last grouping row

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have table favourite_products with schema like below. I need to count how many people (account_id) like product with id = 12. But the condition is that person marked product as liked on last time.

In this example user with id = 1 marked product 12 as positive for the first time, but then he marked is a non-positive so this value shouldn't be returned. The following example should return 2 rows (for user_id = 5 and user_id = 8). I heard about window function but have mysql in version 5.7 and I can't upgrade it. Do you have some ideas how to write this query?

```
| id |  user_id | product_id | positive |
| 1  |     1    |    12      |    1     |
| 2  |     1    |    12      |    0     |
| 3  |     1    |    15      |    1     |
| 4  |     5    |    12      |    1     |
| 5  |     5    |    12      |    1     |
| 6  |    11    |    18      |    1     |
| 7  |     8    |    12      |    1     |
| 8  |     8    |    12      |    1     |
```

Comment: What do you mean by "last time"? What if user 1 dis-liked product 12 then liked it (first 0 then 1)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following approach should work for all the cases, including the case when a product was disliked and then liked again at the end.

In a [Derived table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html), we can get the maximum `id` value for every `user_id` and `product_id = 12`. This result-set will be joined to the main table appropriately. This will fetch us the complete row (recent activity done by user for a product).

Now, we can consider only those users where the last activity is positive.

---

**Query**

```
SELECT fp.user_id
FROM   favourite_products AS fp
       JOIN (SELECT user_id,
                    Max(id) AS max_id
             FROM   favourite_products
             WHERE  product_id = 12
             GROUP  BY user_id) AS dt
         ON dt.user_id = fp.user_id
            AND dt.max_id = fp.id
            AND fp.positive = 1;
```

**Result**

```
| user_id |
| ------- |
| 5       |
| 8       |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gQagCNFpupgH5RMGJXvPDR/0)